# How is the frequency of the dipole oscillation related to the frequency of the wave emitted by the dipole?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, optics, frequency

An oscillating electric dipole with frequency $\omega$ has a power $P\propto \omega^4$. How  is the frequency of the emitted wave related to the dipole oscillation frequency?

Answer (score 0):

The two frequencies are equal. A monochromatic source in a linear system in steady state can only ever produce a monochromatic response at an identical frequency.